# How to disable textbox from editing?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to use a text box to display some text. I can not disable it, because then the scroll bar will not work.

How can I prevent editing within the multi-line textbox, yet make it appear as if it is enabled, so that the scroll bar works correctly?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can set the [ReadOnly property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx) to true.

Quoth the link:

> When this property is set to true, the contents of the control cannot
>   be changed by the user at runtime. With this property set to true, you
>   can still set the value of the Text property in code. You can use this
>   feature instead of disabling the control with the Enabled property to
>   allow the contents to be copied and ToolTips to be shown.

Answer (score 25):

The `TextBox` has a property called `ReadOnly`.  If you set that property to true then the `TextBox` will still be able to scroll but the user wont be able to change the value.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned above, you can change the property of the textbox "Read Only" to "True" from the properties window.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
        textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

"true" property will make the text box readonly activate. and "false" will make it in regular form. Thanks.

Comment: it is cleary stated in the question that disabling is not an option because then the scrollbars would disappear